# How to combine 2 bools together in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, boolean

I'm trying to create a email validation that validates where there is character `@` in the email and characters before and after `@`. I'm able to this but I can't be able to combine both together. So far I have a computed property that just checks if the email contains `@`. How can I combine this together to check all conditions.

```
extension String {

    var isEmailFormat: Bool {
        if let range = self.range(of: "@") {
            _ = self[(self.startIndex)..<range.lowerBound]
            _ = self[range.upperBound...]
        }
        return self.contains("@")
    }
}


if !self.emailField.text!.isEmailFormat {
                self.addErrorMessage("Invalid email address")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional (boolean) clauses are separated from the optional binding with a *comma:*

```
if let range = self.range(of: "@"), condition1, condition2 { ... }
```

However, assiging a slice to `_` does not test anything, it should be something like this:

```
var isEmailFormat: Bool {
    if let range = self.range(of: "@"),
        range.lowerBound > startIndex,
        range.upperBound < endIndex {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
var isEmailFormat: Bool {
    if let range = self.range(of: "@") {
        return range.lowerBound > startIndex && range.upperBound < endIndex
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfect

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use a regular expression in cases like this.

```
func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {        
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
}
```

If you want to use 2 booleans, use a return statement like

return condition1 && condition2

but I'm assuming you already know that.

Comment: I don't wanna use regular expressions

Comment: I think you should if this thing goes online. If you are just playing in a sandbox, you should do 
    let range = self.range(of: "@")
    return range.lowerBound > startIndex && range.upperBound < endIndex
as suggested from other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
var isEmailFormat: Bool {
    if let range = self.range(of: "@"),
       range.lowerBound > self.startIndex,
       range.upperBound < self.endIndex {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Logic behind removing the contains logic

If the string itself not containing the `@` character, then the `range` would be deliberately `nil`. So not required in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Iam using Custom validator 
         func validatorEmail(TF1:UITextField,errorMsg:String = validatorConstants.errorMsg ,errorMsgEmail:String = validatorConstants.emailMsg,fieldName:String = "Email" ) -> Bool {
            var error = validatorConstants.errorMsg
            if fieldName.count > 0 {
              error = validatorConstants.customMsg + fieldName
            }

            if  TF1.text?.isEmpty == true{
             // Any Notification
              return false
            }
            if  TF1.text?.isValidEmail == false{
              // Any Notification
              return false
            }
            return true
          }


  var isValidEmail: Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: self)
}   

              // call  this function as
       guard validator.validators(TF1: self.txtfied,fieldName: "FirstName") == false
          else {
           return
            }
```